# How to map inside map in React to put it into a table?

Tags: reactjs, html-table, array.prototype.map

I'm struggling for a while now trying to get my data into a table.

I have tried different ways to get the data on easiest way from backend.
Latest try gives this one in the `console.log(tableData)`:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
  0: period: "23"
     periodId: 1
     periodQuantity: Array(3)
       0: {period: "23", quantity: 1037, name: "Stolpar Tall"}
       1: {period: "23", quantity: 1077, name: "Stamblock Tall"}
       2: {period: "23", quantity: 590, name: "Grovtimmer Tall"}
       length: 3
       [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
     sortOrder: 0
     [[Prototype]]: Object
  1: {periodId: 2, period: "24", sortOrder: 0, periodQuantity: Array(3)}
  2: {periodId: 3, period: "25", sortOrder: 0, periodQuantity: Array(3)}
  length: 3
  [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

So here is my code in React, just trying to do a simple table just to put out the data. (After that I can style it ;))
I'm trying to do a .map in a .map but i only got error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'periodQuantity' of undefined
```

```
<div>
   <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Sortiment</th>
          {tableData.map(x => {
            return (
              <React.Fragment key={x.periodId}>
                <th key={x.periodId}>Week {x.period}</th>
              </React.Fragment>
            )
          })}
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <th >Sort.Name </th>
           {tableData.map(({ periodQuantity }, i) => {
             {
              this.periodQuantity.map((p) => {
                return(
                   console.log(p),
                   <React.Fragment key={i}>
                      <td key={p.name}>P {p.name}.</td>
                   </React.Fragment>
                )
               })
              }
            })}
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

If I just erase some code, so only the first `.map` exists and put `periodQuantity` in the `console.log(periodQuantity)` it gives me this:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
  0: 
    name: "Sortiment name 1"
    period: "30"
    quantity: 55 
    [[Prototype]]: Object
  1: {period: "30", quantity: 32, name: "Sortiment name 2"}
  2: {period: "30", quantity: 64, name: "Sortiment name 2"}
  ...
  length: 3[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
and so on...
```

So it actually know what periodQuantity is, but what am I doing wrong when i can't make it in the second .map function?

This is how I want it to look like when all data is in the table:

[image: Table with week column header and sortiment name header on the row. Quantity data per sortiment name and week between]

**Update**:

tableData come from this in the index.js (same as the  above):

```
const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([{}]);

 followUpService.GetSortiment(periodDateTime).subscribe(
        (response) => handlePeriod(response),
        (error) => handleHttpRequestError(error.message));

  const handlePeriod = (response: any) => {
    setTableData(response);
  };
```

And that service go into backend and send back this:
[image: the results sending back to frontend]

**Update 2**
I answered my own question. Se answer below. Hope it could help someone in the future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find out that I needed to put an **if (periodQuantity != null)** before my second map, because I think it got read before it has any data.

Here is my final solution, it might help someone in the future :)
I also had to put `name` out of the `periodQuantity` list, and only have `period` and `quantity` inside of that list. But the main reason to my problem with map in map(I think) is that missing `if (periodQuantity != null)` around the second `.map`.

```
<div>
  <table>
     <thead>
        <tr>
          {tableData.slice(0,1).map(({ periodQuantity }) => {
            if (periodQuantity != null) {
              return( 
                <tr> 
                  <th>Sortiment</th>
                  {periodQuantity.map(({ period }) => {
                    return (
                      <React.Fragment >
                         <th key={period}>V.{period}</th>
                      </React.Fragment>
                   )})}
                </tr>
             )}})}
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <tr>
            {tableData.map(({ periodQuantity, name }) => {
              if (periodQuantity != null) {
                return( 
                  <tr> 
                     <th key={name}>{name}</th>
                     {periodQuantity.map(({ period, quantity }) => {
                        return (
                           <React.Fragment >
                              <td key={period}>{quantity}</td>
                           </React.Fragment>
                      )})}
                   </tr>
               )}})}
           </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
this.periodQuantity.map((p) => {
```

Leaving it like

```
periodQuantity.map((p) => {
```

And also return from the first map

```
{tableData.map(({ periodQuantity }, i) => {
              return periodQuantity.map((p) => {
                return(
                   <React.Fragment key={p.name}>
                      <td>P {p.name}.</td>
                   </React.Fragment>
                )
               })
            })}
```

Also changed the key, or it could potentially repeat, that assumes name is unique, and removed key from td

Here a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-platform-kftsv

Comment: I tried to change it but then I got `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` instead on the row `{tableData.map(({ periodQuantity }, i) => {`

Comment: Where you get tableData from? Make sure it is always an array

Comment: I just updated my question above with some more code. The last picture is the last variable sending back to frontend again.